# Get postal codes of a city in OSM via postgis/postgresql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, postal-code

So, I'm trying to get the postal codes of a city (polygon). Unfortunately, I never get consistent results with my code:

```
SELECT
a.name,
b.tags->'postal_code'

FROM planet_osm_polygon a
JOIN planet_osm_polygon b ON ST_Intersects(a.way, b.way)

WHERE a.name = 'cityname'
AND   b.boundary = 'postal_code';
```

With `ST_Intersects` I get all valid postal codes plus a few non-valid surrounding ones.
I also tried a few other functions, like `ST_Crosses`, `ST_Contains`, `ST_Within`, but never got a set of valid postal codes. Is there a best practice out there to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you simply compute the postal_code polygon centroids, and report all centroids inside of the city boundary polygon?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but I guess it won't work in all cases, since I want to run this all over Germany. Centroids might be outside the city boundaries. Will try and keep u posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem an I solved it with the following statement:

```
SELECT
  city.name,
  postcode.tags->'postal_code'

FROM planet_osm_polygon postcode
JOIN planet_osm_polygon city ON ST_INTERSECTS(city.geometry, postcode.geometry)  
  AND NOT ST_Touches(city.geometry, postcode.geometry)

WHERE a.name = 'cityname'
  AND   b.boundary = 'postal_code';
```

Description:
`ST_INTERSECTS` also includes touches see : https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html
so you have to exclude these surrounding postcodes with `ST_TOUCHES`. This function return `TRUE` if an item touches the other and there are no intersection with the inner area. See https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Touches.html . So `ST_TOUCHES(city.geometry, city.geometry)` would return `FALSE` and `ST_TOUCHES(city.geometry, cityNeighbour.geometry)` would return `TRUE` while `ST_INTERSECTS` always returns `TRUE`.